# Selecting specific values on script bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, debian

I need to get some informations from this string (df command)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        19G  3.8G   14G  22% /
```

I need to get:

- The available space value
- And the used space value

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
df / | awk 'FNR>1 {print $3, $4}'
```

Comment: I think using this code, it will also wirte "Used, Avail", how to get rid of this?

Comment: Did toy try it. by passing your specific Filesystem to grep you can get just Used and Avail fields

Comment: And if I don't use grep on filesystems, and using commands like this
`df / | awk'{print $3, $4}` , how can I solve this?

Comment: If you want to get these values for all disk, then instead of the `grep` there, you can use `tail +2`

Comment: @user2834656 Look at the update for getting desire output, Thanks to janos help. This will skip the first line.

Comment: @janos, there's no reason to use `tail`; just add a record number test in the awk.  Eg, `df / | awk 'FNR>1 {print $3, $4}'`

Comment: @jwpat7 Spot on! Yeah that's better, saving one process.

Answer (score 0):

To print the columns of the second line of the command, you can use `awk` or similar:

```
$ df -h / | awk 'FNR==2 {print $1, "used: " $3, "avail: " $4}'
```

For scripting purposes you could read the command output into an array and get your values there:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=( $(df -h / | tail +2) )
printf "%s\n" "${line[0]} used: ${line[2]} avail: ${line[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, without awk.

```
df / --output=used,avail | tail -n +2
```